# dealing filenames with shell regex

Tags: shell

```
138.096.000.015.00111-138.096.201.072.38717
138.096.000.015.01008-138.096.201.072.00790
138.096.201.072.00790-138.096.000.015.01008
138.096.201.072.33853-173.194.020.147.00080
138.096.201.072.34293-173.194.034.009.00080
138.096.201.072.38717-138.096.000.015.00111
138.096.201.072.41741-173.194.034.025.00080
138.096.201.072.50612-173.194.034.007.00080
173.194.020.147.00080-138.096.201.072.33853
173.194.034.007.00080-138.096.201.072.50612
173.194.034.009.00080-138.096.201.072.34293
173.194.034.025.00080-138.096.201.072.41741
```

I have many folders inside which there are many files, the file names are like the above
I want to remove those files with file names having substring "138.096.000"

and sometimes I want to get the list of files with filenames with substring "00080"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete files with name containing "138.096.000":

```
find /root/of/files -type f -name '*138.096.000*' -exec rm {} \;
```

To list files with names containing "00080":

```
find /root/of/files -type f -name '*00080*'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rm $(find . -name \*138.096.000\*)
```

This uses the find command to find the appropriate files. This is executed within a *subshell*, and the output (the list of files) is used by `rm`. Note the escaping of the * pattern, since the shell will try and expand `*` itself.

This assumes you don't have filenames with spaces etc. You may prefer to do something like:

```
for i in $(find . -name \*138.096.000\*); do
   rm $i
done
```

in this scenario, or even

```
find . -name \*138.096.000\* | xargs rm
```

Note that in the loop above you'll execute `rm` for each file, and the `xargs` variant will execute `rm` multiple times (dependin gon the number of files you have - it may only execute once).

However, if you're using [zsh](http://www.zsh.org) then you can simply do:

```
rm **/*138.096.000*
```

(I'm assuming your directories aren't named like your files. Note the `-f` flag as used in Kamil's answer if this is the case)